# On the boundary conditions of the Casimir effect and quantization of the wave vector

Tags: quantum-field-theory, boundary-conditions, second-quantization, casimir-effect

I'm reviewing the famous Casimir effect. I'm uploading an image with the starting setup and frame of reference. [image]

The electric field field operator is:
[image]

where $\textbf{e}$ is the polarization vector, $\vec{k} = (k_x,k_y,k_z)$ is the wave vector, $\omega_k = c|\vec{k}|$, V is the volume we are considering that is $V = L^2d$, $\hat{a}$ is the creation operator with its hermitian conjugate.

The quantization of the wave vector comes from imposing the right boundary conditions on the electric field. I should obtain this:
$$
\vec{k} = (\frac{2\pi}{L}m, \frac{2\pi}{L}n, \frac{\pi}{d}l)
$$
with $m$ and $n$ integers, while $l$ a *positive* integer. 
The x and y components of the wave vector come from imposing the so-called periodic boundary conditions. I'm having some problems deriving the third component. It comes from evaluating the electric field on the metal plates, so at $z=0$ and $z=d$. I did get that the component is the one I wrote before, but I did not get to the condition that $l$ should be a positive integer. From my passages I get that $l$ could also be negative, just like $m$ and $n$. I have not found a complete derivation of this passage, so I'm asking for some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fourier series of a function $f(x)$ with periodic boundary conditions $f(x+L)=f(x)$ has the form $$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} a_n \,  e^{2\pi i n x/L}.$$ On the other hand, a function $g(z)$ with boundary conditions $g(0)=g(d)=0$ has the series expansion $$g(z)=\sum\limits_{\ell \in \mathbb{N}} c_\ell \, \sin(\ell \pi z/d).$$ In the first case, $\exp (2\pi i n x/L)$ and $\exp(-2\pi i n x/L)$ are linear independent (thus the summation over all integers $n \in \mathbb{Z}$), in the second case, you have $\sin(-\ell \pi z/d)= -\sin(\ell \pi z/d)$ and the summation goes only over $\ell \in \mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$.

The explicit form of the electric field of your problem is most easily obtained from the associated vector potential $\vec{A}$ in the Coulomb gauge, fulfilling
$$ \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{A} =0, \qquad
\square \vec{A}=0, \qquad 
\vec{A}=\vec{A}^\ast \tag{1} \label{1} $$ together with the boundary conditions
$$\begin{align} \vec{A}(t,x,y,z)&=\vec{A}(t,x+L,y,z)=\vec{A}(t,x,y+L,z) \tag{2} \label{2} \\[3pt] A_{x,y}(t,x,y,0)&=A_{x,y}(t,x,y,d)=0, \tag{3} \label{3} \\[3pt] \nabla_z A_z(t,x,y,0)&=\nabla_z A_z(t,x,y,d)=0. \tag{4} \label{4}  \end{align} $$
Eq. \eqref{2} corresponds to periodic boundary conditions in $x$- and $y$-direction, whereas \eqref{3} and \eqref{4} guarantee $\vec{E}_{||}=0$, $\dot{\vec{B}}_\perp=0$ and $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{A} =0$ on the surface of the plates at $z=0$ and $z=d$.

The general solution of this system of equations is given by
$$\begin{align} A_{x,y}(t,\vec{r})&= \! \sum\limits_{\vec{n}} \sum\limits_s \mathcal{N}(\vec{n}) \, \varepsilon_{x,y}(\vec{n},s) \sin\frac{n_z \pi z}{d}\left[i e^{\frac{2\pi i}{L}(n_x x +n_y y)} e^{-i \omega(\vec{n})t}a(\vec{n},s) + \text{c.c.}    \right],   \tag{5} \label{5}\\[5pt]
A_z(t, \vec{r}) &=  \!  \sum\limits_{\vec{n}} \sum\limits_s \mathcal{N}(\vec{n}) \, \varepsilon_z(\vec{n},s) \cos \frac{n_z \pi z}{d} \left[e^{\frac{2\pi i}{L}(n_x x+n_y y)} e^{-i \omega(\vec{n})t} a(\vec{n},s) +\text{c.c.}  \right], \tag{6} \label{6} \end{align}$$ where $\vec{r}=(x,y,z)$, $\vec{n}=(n_x,n_y,n_z)  \in \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{N}$. Defining $$\vec{k}(\vec{n})= \left(\frac{2\pi n_x}{L}, \frac{2\pi n_y}{L},\frac{\pi n_z}{d} \right),\qquad n_{x,y} \in \mathbb{Z}, \; n_z \in \mathbb{N}, \tag{7} \label{7}$$ the angular frequency $\omega(\vec{n})$ is given by $$\omega(\vec{n})= |\vec k(\vec{n})| = \sqrt{ \left(\frac{2\pi}{L}\right)^{\! 2}(n_x^2+n_y^2)+\left(\frac{\pi }{d}\right)^2 n_z^2}. \tag{8} \label{8} $$ The two (normalized) polarization vectors $\vec{\varepsilon}(\vec{n},1)$, $\vec{\varepsilon}(\vec{n},2)$ (corresponding to the two possible linear polarizations for a given vector $\vec{k}(\vec{n})$) satisfy  $$\vec{k}(\vec{n}) \cdot \vec{\varepsilon}(\vec{n},s) =0, \qquad \vec\varepsilon(\vec{n},s)\cdot \vec\varepsilon(\vec{n},s^\prime) = \delta_{s s^\prime}. \tag{9} $$ Finally, $\mathcal{N}(\vec{n})$ is a conveniently chosen normalization factor to be discussed later.

Taking advantage of \eqref{7}, the vector potential can be written in the slightly more compact form
$$\begin{align}A_{x,y}(t, \vec{r})&= \sum\limits_{\vec{k}, s} \mathcal{N}(\vec{k}) \, \varepsilon_{x,y}(\vec{k}, s) \sin(k_z z) \left[i e^{i(k_x x+k_y y)} e^{-i \omega(\vec{k}) t} a(\vec{k},s) +\text{c.c.}  \right], \tag{10} \label{10} \\[5pt]
A_z(t, \vec{r}) &= \sum\limits_{\vec{k},s} \mathcal{N}(\vec{k}) \, \varepsilon_z(\vec{k}, s) \cos(k_z z) \left[e^{i(k_x x+k_y y)} e^{-i \omega(\vec{k}) t} a(\vec{k},s) + \text{c.c.}  \right].   \tag{11} \label{11}     \end{align}$$ The *correct* expression for the electric field $\vec{E}= -\dot{\vec{A}}$ is thus given by
$$\begin{align} E_{x,y}(t, \vec{r}) &=-\sum\limits_{\vec{k},s} \mathcal{N}(\vec{k})\,  \omega(\vec{k})\, \varepsilon_{x,y}(\vec{k},s) \sin(k_z z) \left[ e^{i(k_x x+k_y y)} e^{-i \omega(\vec{k}) t} a(\vec{k},s) + \text{c.c.}  \right], \tag{12} \label{12} \\[5pt] 
E_z(t, \vec{r}) &= i \sum\limits_{\vec{k},s} \mathcal{N}(\vec{k}) \, \omega(\vec{k}) \, \varepsilon_z(\vec{k},s)  \cos(k_z z) \left[e^{i(k_x x+k_y y)} e^{-i \omega(\vec{k}) t} a(\vec{k},s) + \text{c.c.} \tag{13} \label{13} \right].       \end{align} $$ Note the expression for $\vec{E}$ displayed  in your question  is apparently in conflict with the boundary conditions discussed above (in particular, $\vec{E}_{||}=0$ at the plates is *not* fulfilled).

The quantization of the system is now straightforward. Choosing $\mathcal{N}(\vec{k}) $ such that the energy  $$ H= \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^L\! \!dx \int\limits_0^L \!\!dy \int\limits_0^d \!\!dz \,(\vec{E}^2 + \vec{B}^2) \tag{14}$$ takes the form $$H  = \sum\limits_{\vec{k},s} \omega(\vec{k}) a^\ast(\vec{k},s) a(\vec{k},s), \tag{15}$$ the Fourier coefficients are promoted to operators acting in Fock space, obeying the commutation relations $$[a(\vec{k},s), a^\dagger(\vec{k}^\prime, s^\prime)]= \delta_{\vec{k} \, \vec{k}^\prime} \, \delta_{s \, s^\prime}, \qquad [a(\vec{k},s), a(\vec{k}^\prime,s^\prime)]=0, \tag{16}$$ describing a a system of infinitely many (uncoupled) quantum harmonic oscillators.

Comment: I understand the point here. Still, I have some difficulties seeing the sine function arising inside the Electric field operator once I plug $k_z$... In fact, if I plug $k_z = \frac{l\pi}{d}$ the electric field should be zero, but I don't see it really... ( I'm referring to the expression of the electric field written above)

Comment: @GiulianoArtale $e^{i \alpha}-e^{-i \alpha}=2 i \sin \alpha$

Comment: Yeah but in this case I got something more like $Ae^{i\alpha} - Be^{-i\alpha}$ where inside A and B are the creation and annihilation operators... Are they not playing a role?

Comment: @GiulianoArtale You have to identify the *independent* Fourier coefficients. The most transparent way to find the result is the following: 1. Write down the expression for the vector potential as a Fourier series with the correct boundary conditions. 2. Impose the constraints following from $\vec{A}^\ast=\vec{A}$, $(\partial_t^2-\Delta)\vec{A}=0$ and $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{A}=0$. 3. Compute $\vec{E}=- \partial_t \vec{A}$.

Comment: @GiulianoArtale Expanding my last comment, I have now added a full discussion of the derivation of the electric field with the relevant boundary conditions in my answer.